# Kotlin Same Fragment Multiple Activities

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, navigation, fragment

friends, I have a question. I can use the fragment in the image in an activity. But I want to be able to view this fragment in a different activity. Is it possible? I used a structure like the one in the image, but I am also writing the error I received. I would be glad if you could help.

> BreakingNewsFragment.kt

```
class BreakingNewsFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_breaking_news) {

    lateinit var viewModel: NewsViewModel
    lateinit var viewModel2:NewsViewModel
    lateinit var newsAdapter: NewsAdapter

    val TAG = "BreakingNewsFragment"

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = (activity as NewsActivity).viewModel
        viewModel2=(activity as UsNewsActivity).viewModel

        setupRecyclerView()

        newsAdapter.setOnItemClickListener {
            val bundle = Bundle().apply {
                putSerializable("article", it)
            }
            findNavController().navigate(
                R.id.action_breakingNewsFragment_to_articleFragment,
                bundle
            )
        }

        viewModel.breakingNews.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { response ->
            when(response) {
                is Resource.Success -> {
                    hideProgressBar()
                    response.data?.let { newsResponse ->
                        newsAdapter.differ.submitList(newsResponse.articles.toList())
                        val totalPages=newsResponse.totalResults/ QUERY_PAGE_SIZE+2 //Sayfada boşluk oluşuyor
                        isLastPage=viewModel.breakingNewsPage==totalPages
                        if(isLastPage){
                            rvBreakingNews.setPadding(0,0,0,0)
                        }
                    }
                }
                is Resource.Error -> {
                    hideProgressBar()
                    response.message?.let { message ->
                        Log.e(TAG, "An error occured: $message")
                    }
                }
                is Resource.Loading -> {
                    showProgressBar()
                }
            }
        })

    }
```

> Error

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.androiddevs.mvvmnewsapp.ui.NewsActivity cannot be cast to com.androiddevs.mvvmnewsapp.ui.UsNewsActivity
at com.androiddevs.mvvmnewsapp.ui.fragments.BreakingNewsFragment.onViewCreated(BreakingNewsFragment.kt:34)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you get this when creating your fragment from a `NewsActivity`?
You are trying to treat a `UsNewsActivity` as a `NewsActivity` which it isn't.

just go:

```
val viewModel: NewsViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

as suggested [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing). It should give you the `ViewModel` used in the `Activity`.

If you want to stick to the way you are doing things now, you could either implement an `interface` in your activities like

```
interface NewsActivityInterface {
    val viewModel: NewsViewModel
}
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NewsActivityInterface {
    override val viewModel: NewsViewModel by viewModels()
    (...)
}
```

and then get your viewmodel like

```
viewModel = (activity as NewsActivityInterface).viewModel
```

or check type:

```
val viewModel = activity.let{
    when (it){
        is MainActivity -> it.viewModel
        is AnotherActivity -> it.viewModel
        else -> error ("Needs correct activity")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I tried your last option and it was successful.